# Rendering Problems Exception android.graphics.drawable

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I'm getting this Error :

> Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable_Delegate.nDraw(JJJLandroid/graphics/Rect;ZZ)

I know that I can change from " N preview" version  to  "23" and it will work  but what I have to do so that it works on "preview"?

I tried:

- clearing  and rebuilding
- installed sdk tools
- invalidate caches /restart

Comment: Same issue as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544129/exception-raised-during-renderingbinary-xml-file-line-1error-inflating-class

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can change the target for the preview in the top right button of the preview area, like in the picture below:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have the same problem but my menu doesn't show "API 23: Android API 23", just the preview. I targeted my project at N on creation.

Comment: Whenever I have it set to Pick Best it picks N. Any ideas on why it still doesn't show, or assumes that N is best when clearly it's not working?

Comment: Cody, try to select "API 23: Android API 23"

Comment: @akarnokd try with the solution as suggested by accepted answer.

Comment: @CodyHarness try with the solution as suggested by accepted answer.

Comment: select android wear instead of Nexus4

Answer (score 11):

**A**utomatically **P**ick **B**est does not work for some time when latest not installed perfectly. And probably `android studio` pick **A**utomatically **P**ick **B**est by default. So in that case we have to select fully installed manually. For more detail and reference check [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview/36223213#36223213)

Comment: This often happens if you have your own custom created or edited theme added to your app from the manifest.
Try changing the theme to your custom theme in the preview, just where you were changing the android API version.
It might work. It worked for me.