# Rendering problems:The following classes could not be instantiated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

After update android studio to 2.1 when I create project with basic activity then it shows me error like below.
I tried to change android API and also change project theme in style.xml file,but still shows same error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you get this error because you haven't add support.design library to your project correctly.
Doing these steps may solves your problem:

0- Change the target for the preview in the top right button of the preview area, like this:

[image]

1- Go to your SDK Manager and under the 'extras' section, check 'Android Support Library' and check it for installation. if you have done that before.

2- Add Support.design library to your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0'
```

Then click "Synch Now" and gradle will get that library for you. then you can use support.design widgets in your UI.

3- Change `res/values/styles.xml` like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
```

Comment: I already add this library  " compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0' " .should I change that library to " compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0' " ?

Comment: no it's ok. that is for version of your support library.Did you try synch and rebuild your project

Comment: Thanks,problem solved by installing Android Support Library.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your SDK is not update correctly. Check again your SDK and download & install latest API correctly. for further detail check [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview/36223213#36223213) OR [This One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658009/rendering-problems-exception-android-graphics-drawable?noredirect=1&lq=1) these both indicate the rendering problem solution.

Answer (score -2):

Change the parent layout 
`<CoordinatorLayout>` to `<LinearLayout>` or `<RelativeLayout>`

will solve your problem