# Preview is unavailable until a successful build

Tags: android-studio

I tried fixing this for ages now, but I don't know what to do. How do I get it to display a preview? Here is a screenshot of the code:

[image: img]

Comment: Click on clean project and rebuild project. After you can see preview design.  :)

Answer (score 25):

Solved :

Try 1 : Just close and open the Android Studio

Try 2 : Build -> Clean project -> rebuild

Try 3 : Build -> Clean project -> rebuild -> restart Android studio

Mi

Comment: Just close and open the Android Studio. Worked for me

Answer (score 14):

From Menu Open file option and choose option Close Project.

then restart your project android.

this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 5):

in my case, clean and build didn't work, I just close the project and open it again, it's solved

Answer (score 4):

The attached screenshot shows your Project is not sync properly. Here are some of the possible steps:

1. Use `Sync Project with Gradle Files` for more [Here is answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075498/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name/32431220#32431220) with more detail.
2. If you made huge changes to  project or changed package names etc. use `rebuild`
   In menu Build => Rebuild Project.
3. Preview may not show if an API is selected that is not properly installed. [Check Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658009/rendering-problems-exception-android-graphics-drawable/38189813#38189813).

One of the above should fix the problem. If none of the above work try restarting IDE (`Android Studio`).

Comment: Rebuild does not work. Just `Sync Project with Gradle Files` does.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps-

1. If you have any incomplete statement(s) in your code (probably where
   you left it last time) then comment those lines to make them
   inactive.
2. Go to Build=>Rebuild to rebuild the project.
3. Uncomment those lines to make them active again and you are done!!

Answer (score 3):

Close the android studio and reopen the project again.
If not work replace all '**compile**' with '**implementation**' from **build.gradle** file.
Because it is obsolete now and will be removed at the end of 2018.
I solved this kind of problem like that.

Answer (score 2):

I tried above answers. But, sometimes they work and sometimes not.

I tried -

File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart -> Invalidate and restart

And it always works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I do this to solved the problem:

1. type `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `A` to open the "Actions" search window
2. input "Sync Project with Gradle Files" , then type `Enter`
3. wait for Sync finished