# Android 3.0 Canary 5 layout editor issue

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am new in android studio, and i just installed the version 3.0 canary 5 because it's supports Kotlin (and i want to learn kotlin). When I create i new project, the design editor seems to not work properly. When i drag a a component like a button, he just go on the corner and become not visible. But when i run the app and view it in my android phone it works correctly. The problem i guess is just with the design editor of android studio.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZFDQ.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you read 1 warning and 2 errors at the bottom of preview? And please share your XML codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution [Android Studio does not show layout preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview)

I had the same issue with AS 3.0 canary 5