# Android Studio not displaying device preview

Tags: android

[image]

It doesn't display a preview, and I have the SDK set on settings

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview

Comment: @JohnJoe this doesn't pertain to my question because of SDK, thats why I included that part

Comment: How you know the problem related to SDK?

Comment: When I try to run it it still tells me to set SDK

Comment: In first image on top bar is showing not `sdk` selected as `sdk` is null. try selecting a sdk

Comment: clicking that button it shows no options to select from. Other projects work except this one

Comment: Then may be you are missing something in sdk