# Android Studio 3.1 layout editor blank

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I recently updated Android Studio to version 3.1, and was using the layout editor without problems until today.
 I'm getting two separate errors, one is "Preview timed out while rendering the layout." in the editor itself, and the layout and blueprint are blank; And the other is that in my styles.xml it shows "Cannot resolve symbol" for Theme.
I don't understand if these are related to each other. What could be causing these errors?

I've tried:

- Invalidate Cache/Restart;
- Changing gradle plugin version;
- Selecting another theme;
- Selecting another api level;

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa4

Comment: thanks, I've gone through it, but still nothing. I'll add what I've tried to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually one of my fragment layouts, recreated it from scratch and it worked. I am using constraint layout.