# Preview not updating when changing xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android studio and I've setted a background image in this way  :

```
android:background="@drawable/logo"
```

But the preview screen it's just white, on the phone app I can see the image perfectly. Same thing happens when I've added an image button like this :

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/login" />
```

I don't get it. What am I doing wrong? Also I've tried pressing 'R' on the preview view, but when the spinner finished, nothing happened.

Thank you.

Comment: Post the entire activity code so that we can see whats wrong.

Comment: what version of android studio you are using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview

Answer (score 0):

Invalidating cache and restarting usually solves these for me.

If you're on a mac: File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...