# Android Studio: Preview not displaying

Tags: android

I am new to Android Studio and I can't view the objects in the Preview section. I also have a 'Render Problem' and 'Failed to instantiate one or more classes' problem. When I first open the app without making any modifications, I can't even see the 'Hello World' text in the Preview Section. How can I view the objects that I drag and drop into the design?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio does not show layout preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview)

Answer (score 0):

Encountering the same problem. I added "Base." to the styles resource.[image].
Or you can create your project by unchecking the "backward compatibility" box.
[image]