# Android xml Preview showing Null in devices spinner

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Devices shown as `null` in android preview `xml` `layout` mode, and no `layout` is shown , see attached Screen Shot .. This is not rendering problem, i tried to clean, rebuild, invalidate caches/restart but i did not worked for me , also tried to update support design libraries in gradle based on other answers on stackoverflow but it also not worked for me [image]

Comment: Try to `Clean` and `Rebuild` your project.

Comment: already tried but still getting same error

Comment: Then what's the error ? And why you are selected device is showing to `null` ?

Comment: can you please set zoom level to 40 % , currently it is 200%

Comment: you can see in screen shot , no layout design is shown and devices spinner only show <null>

Comment: You have to select an device to get the preview according to it.

Comment: no problem with zoom level dude,

Comment: do one thing, on left side of **AppTheme** near to zoom level , there you see an option showing **null**, change it's API Level example to 27 or some other. That will help you

Comment: Check my answer , problem solved with File > Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio does not show layout preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 Android Studio > File > Sync Project with Gradle Files
```

i am posting answer to my own question because i solved this problem with sync project with gradle files option,All other stuff like clean, rebuild project , invalidate cache/restart did not worked at all  Thanks

Comment: Your Problem is solved so please delete this question, because many duplicate question like this in SO.

Comment: did not found similar questions that is why i posted the question .

Comment: what is this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview

Comment: yes i tried answers from above question but did not worked for me , my question is different , it was not rendering problem ,

Comment: so no point in giving -1 to my question , as my question was totally different

Comment: i was unabe to choose devices for layout preview

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps, in order if one does not work try the next one

1. Switch to text editor (button at bottom), Check if there are any errors in the layout.
2. In the text editor too there is a preview part so you can check if that is working
3. Build clean (Preview is not shown if build is not successful)
4. Invalidate cache and restart
5. Update Android studio