# Android Studio 3.1.4 does not show layout preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-3.1-honeycomb

I recently installed an update of android studio v 3.1.4 and I am trynig to design some Layout for my app . But the previous does not showing the result of my Xml code .  When i synchronize the project it run succefully  ..where is the matter ?

i  tried many time to fix this problem by changing some dependencies to make it work
such as 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3' :
by other version but still always not showing the previous .
i also tried to clean and rebuild the project .

[image]

```
> Here some files   
> 
> > main_activity.xml
> > 
> > > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> > > <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
> > > xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> > >     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
> > >     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> > >     android:layout_width="match_parent"
> > >     android:layout_height="match_parent"
> > >     tools:context=".MainActivity">
> > > 
> > > 
> > > <RelativeLayout
> > >     android:id="@+id/rel"
> > >     android:layout_width="match_parent"
> > >     android:layout_height="match_parent">
> > 
> >     <FrameLayout
> >         android:id="@+id/main_container"
> >         android:layout_width="match_parent"
> >         android:layout_height="match_parent"
> >         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
> >         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
> >         android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
> > 
> >         <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
> >             android:id="@+id/all_users"
> >             android:layout_width="match_parent"
> >             android:layout_height="match_parent">
> > 
> >         </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
> >     </FrameLayout> </RelativeLayout>
> > 
> >     <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
> >         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
> >         android:layout_height="match_parent"
> >        android:layout_gravity="start"
> >         android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
> > 
> > </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**APP.GRADLE**

> ```
>     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> ```

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chaabane.takwa.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
   .................
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'


    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**

**> PROJECT.BUILD**

**

```
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'



        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: you should checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview

Comment: You can try `clean`ing and then `build`ing the project.

Comment: i tried that and it still not working  @Rishav

Comment: Did you try `invalidate caches and restart`?

Comment: Use stable versions like 28.0.0 or 27.1.1.

Comment: All of your solutions did not work for me only when I updated to the 3.2 version . Thank you guys .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and to resolve it you need to temporally downgrade

```
compileSdkVersion 28 -> 27
targetSdkVersion 28 -> 27

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3' --> 27.1.1
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3' --> 27.1.1
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3' --> 27.1.1
```

I think there is a problem on those library when Android Studio have to render XML layout.

Alternatively, Google released yesterday Android Studio 3.2.0
Upgrade your IDE, change support libraries with 28.0.0 and everything will work

Comment: Maybe there was some other libraries which broke the rendering but upgrading Android Studio is the best solution if you want to support API 28

Answer (score 1):

Try to change in styles.xml this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
```

to this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
```

Answer (score 0):

In style.xml, try add Base.Theme

Answer (score 0):

go to file option and choose invalidate cache and restart android studio