# What type of problem is this in Android Studio 3.5.1?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-studio-3.0

I can not call most of the XML properties like gravity, width, height, margin, background, etc. in my project and I am working on this project for 20 days. Image button images and background images are not showing.

I've already
1.updated the sdks tools.
2.cleaned the project and rebuild it
3.invalidated and restarted caches

But when I created a new project to check why these properties were not being called, I found this result and am facing the same issue.

The first image is the previous project image.
[image: Previous Project Images not showing]
[image: New Project] [image]
While the second image is the new project image, I tried to drag and drop but nothing is showing here & when I move the arrow over this it is showing mock view on the arrow tip window.

Comment: Make sure `ConstraintLayout` dependency added to your app module `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @Bek androidx dependency is already added

Comment: have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview)

Comment: @MohammedAlaa I already do this but it also happens for a new project

Comment: @TARUNSHARMA try to delete `yourDrive:/.AndroidStudio3.5.1/` cache Dir

Comment: Thanks @MohammedAlaa Finally its working :-)

Answer (score 0):

implement this dependency into your build.gradle file.

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'