# Include layout file into constraint layout without affecting performance or Android Studio previews

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a huge layout file with one flat constraint layout within.

I have `android.support.constraint.Group` elements that are identical. I want to move these to a separate file and then include them like `<include layout="@layout/selection_group"/>`

The problem I'm facing is that the group that I have in the file `selection_group.xml` is not previewed correctly in Android studio. Is there a way to make Android Studio preview this directly in the file or include them in a different way?

selection_group.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_config_one_background_group"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bar_background_with_border_fx"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="top_bar_config_one,top_bar_tooth_one"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/top_bar_container_background"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/top_bar_container_background"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/top_bar_config_two"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_bar_container_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_config_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_height_over_sea_100x26"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/top_bar_tooth_one"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/top_bar_container_background"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/top_bar_config_two"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_bar_config_one_background_group" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_tooth_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_tooth_auto_40x40"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/top_bar_config_one_background_group"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/top_bar_container_background"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/top_bar_config_two" />
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
</layout>
```

I don't want to nest multiple constraint layouts together. I think the root `<layout>` view in `selection_group.xml` is optimized and does not affect the performance? My goal is to reduce redundant code and not affect performance

Comment: Did you try to invalidate cache and restart android studio?
You can check out this thread too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview If this helps your cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try added a *merge* tag to the included layout:

```
<layout>
    <merge>
    <group>
    ... etc. ...
    </merge>
</layout>
```

Comment: Merge was exactly what I needed. Right-click refactor -> layout did this for me I figured. Didn't need the outer <layout> tags.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make that layout file ready to be included you need to replace `<layout>` with `<merge>`

In case you need to use DataBinding into your layout you need to have `<layout` first and than `<merge>` tags on top of the layout file

I order to have proper preview in your inner layout which is going to be included - add on top level into merge tag:

> tools:parentTag="ContraintLayout"

Something like this:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout">
```