# The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Tags: android, xml, material-design, materialcardview

I am developing android app and I have used MaterialCardView but I am getting following exception

```
the following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.material.R$attr   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)   at com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView.<clinit>   ... (MaterialCardView.java:90)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:659)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501) Copy stack to clipboard
```

below my xml file where I have used MaterialCardView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">
    
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivUser"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
    
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivUser"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="TextView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvName"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvName"
                tools:text="TextView" />
    
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

below my app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "yodgorbekkomilov.edgar.printfultask"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.3'
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:1.4.0"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-network:1.4.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0'
    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

    // Annotation processor
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - helpers for implementing LifecycleOwner in a Service
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

below my night/themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.PrintfulApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

below values/themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.PrintfulApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

I want to know where exactly I am making mistake I have tried to change for another themes as well and I have tried invalidate cache restart rebuild and build project and followed all stackoverflow suggestions it did not solve my issue any hints greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I tried to update dependencies and invalidate caches, but it didn't help.

Then I downgraded Android Studio from `Dolphin` to `Chipmunk`. You can also upgrade it or choose another from Beta or Canary build.

Comment: It works now after downgrade AS to Chipmunk...