# Android Studio (Navigation Drawer Issue)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K41pp.png)

I was trying to make a navigation drawer on Android Studio but It seems my design display is not working. Nothing is showing. I have no idea what is happening. Hope someone can help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run your app on your Emulator or Physical device? Sometimes Android Studio doesn't render your components in Layout Editor.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview), it may help you.

Comment: I'm using a physical device for that. Let me try your link first.