# My Android Studio layout preview is not Working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, ide

I just cleared Cache in Explorer, Restart Android Studio & Invalidate Cache.

Here are my layouts and they are unchanged.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview/36223213

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio does not show layout preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview)