# Layout preview rendering issue in Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, preview

In android studio layout preview not displayed. Multiple times i delete the idea file and clear, rebuild,invalidate cache, restart All options i have tried but issue got remain.these are the android studio i am using (Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1) and Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1.Not only single TextView layout rendering. i spent lot of time in it but not got any solution. Please suggest me any solution or need to change in android studio settings so i can see layout Design run time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Notifications"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Layout code please.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Notifications"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
        
</LinearLayout>

Comment: umesh: try this: change `xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Comment: Already used http://

Comment: but it is not included in your comment?!!

Comment: Its removed automatically here when i posted the code here. but in My xml file existed.

Comment: have you tried answers of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34499839/6576302)?

Comment: Yes i have tried some of way from this post. but not getting any solution. Can you share gradle file setting or which jdk compatible with these android studio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255456/discussion-between-umesh-and-c-f-g).